# binding Resolution Exception in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm working in a new project in laravel.I am in starting state of the project.
At initial , I try to run the install spatie/laravel-backup package from composer. It shows the binding Resolution Exception.
then , i leave to installation.
I then start to make dynamic the heading. and try to redirect the title button to the welcome page through route.but it still shows the bindingResolutionException as of before.

web.php

```html
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;<br>
use App\Http\Controllers;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('landing');
```

sidebar.blade.php

```html
<a href="{{ route('landing')  }}" target="_new">
            <img src="images/icon/logo.png" alt="Cool Admin" />
            <span>SikchyaJtoti</span>
        </a>
```

In the terminal mode, it shows :
Illuminate/contracts/container/BindingResolutionException
Target [Spatie/Backup/Tasks/Cleanup/Cleanupstrategy] is not instantialble while building [Spatie/Backup/Commands/CleanupCommand]
[command error][2]

Comment: What do you want to use the Spatie Backup plugin for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
composer remove spatie/laravel-backup
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer require spatie/laravel-backup
composer update
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Ok thats perfect, please vote my answer up and accept it as the final answer